# JavaScript Data Not Appending to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object of values and I am trying to populate two arrays with the keys and values from the object.

My Object:

```
obj = {19455746: 7476, 22489710: 473}
```

Loop attempting to append data:

```
var sensorNameArray = [];
var sensorDataArray = [];
for(var i in obj) {
  sensorNameArray.push[i];
  sensorDataArray.push[obj[i]];
}
```

At the moment the two arrays are printing out as empty. My expected outout would be something like:

```
sensorNameArray = [19455746, 22489710];
sensorDataArray = [7476, 473];
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect, it should be `push()`, not `push[]`

Comment: haha thanks, don't know how I didn't spot that. All working now.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm if you want to add that comment as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Alright, will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `push[]` doesn't invoke the function, it tries to access a property of the function object. It doesn't throw an error because in Javascript, functions ARE objects and this syntax is technically valid.

So, just fix the syntax to `push()` in order to actually invoke the function.

Answer (score 2):

push is a function, not an array, it uses parenthesis not brackets :

```
for(var i in obj) {
    sensorNameArray.push(i);
    sensorDataArray.push(obj[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different syntax (more elegant IMO) :

```
var sensorNameArray = Object.keys(obj)
var sensorDataArray = Object.values(obj)

or :

var sensorDataArray = sensorNameArray.map( key => obj[key] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using square braces []
but array.push() is a function so use circle braces instead

Try the following code

```
   obj = {19455746: 7476, 22489710: 473};
    var sensorNameArray = [];
    var sensorDataArray = [];
    for(var i in obj) {
      sensorNameArray.push(i);
      sensorDataArray.push(obj[i]);
    }
```

This is working and tested.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to deal with JSON is use lodash or underscore.

_.key() and _.value are functions for your requirement.

Eg.:

```
obj = {19455746: 7476, 22489710: 473};

sensorNameArray = _.keys(obj);
sensorDataArray = _.values(obj);
```

If you want to proceed in your way, then you can use parenthesis as push inbuilt function of Javascript for inserting element into array.

Correct is:

```
for(var i in obj) {
    sensorNameArray.push(i);
    sensorDataArray.push(obj[i]);
}
```

Comment: This isn't JSON

Comment: Ya I'm just suggesting other ways, to access objects, so it might be helpful in future. Correction of current code is also specified.